# updating textview in an activity from a service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

below is an example for updating textiviews in an activity from a service via broadcast receiver but i want to send calculated bandwidth usage from the service to the text views in the other activity, i have tried an approach but its not working (it just shows package names in the text fields)

**broadcast service (transmitter)**

```
    public class BroadcastService  extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.websmithing.broadcasttest.displayevent";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();           
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); // 10 seconds
        }
    };    

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");

        intent.putExtra("time", new Date().toLocaleString());
        intent.putExtra("counter", String.valueOf(++counter));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);       
        super.onDestroy();
    }       
}
```

**Broadcast service (receiver)**

```
public class BroadcastTest extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastTest";
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);       
        }
    };    

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();       
        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BroadcastService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        stopService(intent);        
    }   
    public void ohh(View view) { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
        String counter = intent.getStringExtra("time"); 
        String time = intent.getStringExtra("counter");
        Log.d(TAG, counter);
        Log.d(TAG, time);

        TextView txtDateTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDateTime);   
        TextView txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCounter);
        txtDateTime.setText(time);
        txtCounter.setText(counter);
    }
}
```

**Bandwidth Usage calculator**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private long mStartRX = 0;
    private long mStartTX = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
            alert.show();
        } else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
    }

    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RX);
            TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TX);
            long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
            RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
            long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX;
            TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
     };
}
```

**My approach**

```
public class BroadcastService  extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.websmithing.broadcasttest.displayevent";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private long mStartRX = 0;
    private long mStartTX = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);  
        mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
            alert.show();
        } else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }

    }
    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        //  TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RX);
        //  TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TX);
            long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
      //    RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
            long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX;
       //   TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
     };


    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();           
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); // 10 seconds
        }
    };    

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");

        intent.putExtra("time", new Date().toLocaleString());
        intent.putExtra("counter", String.valueOf(++counter));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);       
        super.onDestroy();
    }       
}
```

i am having problem in transmitting the value of "**rxBytes**" and "**txBytes**" in the line **intent.putExtra("counter", String.valueOf(++counter));**

their values are not being used so the are highlighted with yellow

Comment: Try to use debugger to narrow the issue search. It'a to many lines of code to analyze them manually (at least for me)

Comment: what im trying to do is calculate bandwidth usage in the service and then simply transmit it to the receiver class so that it gets updated in the text fields

Comment: I know what you're trying to do. Just put few breakpoints to check what data is passed between methods, and if they are at least executed.

Comment: just click on left margin to set up break point and start application using debug instead of run (shift+f9 on windows). Simply check if your service is broadcasting, receiver receiving and what.

Comment: If application stops in this point - check what are values of variables, if not - your code is not executed. Look for some tutorials on YT to check how and for to use this tool.

Comment: @piotrpo hello there, please check my recent approach, i am almost there